# Power Series Solution to Differential Equation with Initial Conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

I am trying to find the solution to $y''-2xy'+10y=$ given $y(0)=0, y'(0)=3$.

My work so far:
$$ \sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2} -2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1} +10\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{n}=0$$
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^{n} -2\sum_{n=0}^\infty na_nx^{n} +10\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{n}=0 $$
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty [(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2} -2 na_n+10 a_n]x^n=0 $$
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty [(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2} +8 a_n]x^n=0 $$
$$(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2} +8a_n=0, n=0,1,2,...$$
$$a_{n+2} = \frac{-8a_n}{(n+1)(n+2)}, n=0,1,2,...$$ Next step is finding the recurrence relation and the generalized form for $a_n$, but I am having trouble with this. I know to plug in $n=0$, $n=1$, and so on until the relation can be reduced to $a_0$ and $a_1$ terms, but I cannot seem to successfully find the general form. Any hints or suggestions?

Comment: I think you forgot to include the factor $x $ from $-2xy'$.

Comment: I think the OP did it in the second line, but should not have switched the starting index (it does not matter though). It does affect the first term in the power series though $2a_2 + 10a_0 = 0$, the recurrence relation should be different though I think.

Comment: Not in the second line. he just shifted indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

After writing that the coefficient of $x^n $ is zero , you will get

$$a_{n+2}=\frac {2n-10}{(n+1)(n+2)} a_n$$

and treat the two cases : $n $ even to use $a_0$ and $n $ odd to use $a_1$.

Since $a_0=y (0)=0$, we conclude that
$$a_{2p}=0$$

and since $a_1=y'(0)=3$, we find

$$a_3=\frac {-8}{2\times 3}3 $$
$$a_5=\frac {4}{4\times 5}4$$
$$a_7=0=a_9=a_{11}=.. $$

finally
$$\boxed {y=3x-4x^3+\frac {4}{5}x^5}$$

Comment: You forgot $a_n$ on the RHS

Comment: @Gregory I just added it before you... thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I see where I forgot to include the $n$ term, but I am still having trouble finding a the equations for the general forms. @Salahamam_Fatima

Comment: $$n=0: a_2=\frac{10}{2!}a_0$$
$$n=2: a_4=\frac{6\cdot10}{4!}a_0$$
$$n=4: a_6=\frac{2\cdot6\cdot10}{6!}a_0$$
$$n=6: a_8=\frac{-2\cdot2\cdot6\cdot10}{8!}a_0$$
and for the odd:
$$n=1: a_3=\frac{8}{3!}a_1$$
$$n=3: a_5=\frac{4\cdot8}{5!}a_1$$
$$n=5: a_7=\frac{0\cdot4\cdot8}{7!}a_1 = 0$$
and the rest of the odd terms are 0, but what is the general form for this? Please help @Salahamam_ Fatima

Comment: @BryanChen Is that helpful.

Comment: But how do I go about combining these into a general solution? Sorry if I'm not seeing something blatantly obvious here. @Salahamam_ Fatima

Comment: @BryanChen Now it is correct correct 1000%

Comment: @Salahamam_ Fatima Thank you so much, I was forgetting to include the initial conditions.

Comment: @BryanChen The mistake yiu made is $10a_n-2na_n=8a_n $. false.